# Deactivated HTC Droid Incredible not installing apps

Tags: applications, installation, htc-droid-incredible

I have an old deactivated HTC Droid incredible from Verizon. I decided I was going to use it as like an iTouch, and it works just fine -- but the Google Play Store has vanished both from the home screen and the "Manage Applications" list (when I first turned on the phone after deactivation not after using it for a while).

At first I was okay with that because I could just go download aptoide or some other third party store. But after I downloaded the apk for aptiode and checked the "Allow Installation from unknown sources" when I tapped it to install I got "Do you want to install this applicaion" and the permissions ect. so I clicked install and then suddenly the phone rebooted? It just showed me the HTC logo, then brought up the home screen. I've tried this with several apks and none of them work. It does not have a SIM card slot.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about "deactivated"? Do you mean the SIM was deactivated by your phone provider? If so, try taking it out, and then edit your question to say if that made a difference.

Comment: Well it was using Verizon but the contract expired and this phone was replaced and by a republic wireless phone. I will try removing the sin card now. Thanks

Comment: I did a quick Google search and it turns out the HTC Droid incredible does not have a sim card slot

Comment: What does the SIM card slot have to do with it? Surely the [Droid Incredible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_Incredible) has no SIM card slot, as it would be of no use for a *CDMA* device. @DanHulme that's the trouble with CDMA devices: no SIM to simply change... I'm not familiar with those CDMA devices, but should'nt a de-activation simply disable the *service* (not the phone)? Not even sure whether they can be "unlocked" (no SIM, no SIM-unlock). But I'd check with them for an explanation.

Comment: A lot of the newer Verizon phones actually do have SIM cards, since LTE is a GSM technology. Anyway, I use many devices without service with no problems with Android Market/Google Play. Sounds like the problem is something else. Maybe install a clean stock ROM on your device to fix any software issues.

Comment: Yeah but this isn't a newer phone its like 4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three Droid Incredibles that we have replaced with different phones. The play store still works on all of them.

Check out this [post for the most recent Google Play apk](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/04/19/download-latest-google-play-store-4-0-26/) and side load it.

If that doesn't work, I would recommend doing a factory reset. It seems like your system has gotten confused.

Alos, look into [Airplane Mode Wifi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.geekherd.airplanemode&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm5ldC5nZWVraGVyZC5haXJwbGFuZW1vZGUiXQ..) app to keep your wireless radio off but leave your wifi on.

Comment: But half the problem is that I can't install apks.

Comment: I tried that apk and got nothing. Just the normal reboot thing.

Comment: Also I think I've heard about not being able to reset without Verizon giving it a new number.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do a factory reset now.

Comment: Glad something worked. Factory resets can be a pain but they often solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long shot, but have you tried [using adb to install apks](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/how-to-install-apps-using-adb-4482/)?